# Excel Offset is returning a #VALUE! error when the height is >1 (Excel 2010)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula, offset

I've set up Names with the intention of using them to return data ranges for a line chart. The X values are "GI", "IE" and "EE". The Y value is "DATE".

However, my "DATE" and "GI" names are returning "#VALUE!" errors - whereas IE and EE are not.

So far, I have found that this error occurs when the height value (CountIf below) is more than 1.

The cell range, and beyond to 2000-and-something, are dynamically generated from user selections to form a Date Range. Ergo the use of CountIf rather than CountA.

Any help would be much appreciated. This is the last leg of a difficult workbook!

DATE:

```
=OFFSET(Graph!$B$8,0,0,COUNTIF(Graph!$B$8:$B$2927,">"&0)-1)
```

GI:

```
=OFFSET(Graph!$C$8,0,0,COUNTIF(Graph!$C$8:$C$2927,">"&0)-1)
```

IE:

```
=OFFSET(Graph!$D$8,0,0,COUNTIF(Graph!$D$8:$D$2927,">"&0)-1)
```

EE:

```
=OFFSET(Graph!$E$8,0,0,COUNTIF(Graph!$E$8:$E$2927,">"&0)-1)
```

Information:

```
      B             C       D   E
7     DATE          GI      IE  EE
8     25/04/2011    0       0   0
9     26/04/2011    0       0   0
10    27/04/2011    0       0   0
11    28/04/2011    0       0   0
12    29/04/2011    0       0   0
13    30/04/2011    0       0   0
14    01/05/2011    0       0   0
15    02/05/2011    0       0   0
16    03/05/2011    0       0   0
17    04/05/2011    0       0   0
18    05/05/2011    0       0   0
19    06/05/2011    0       0   0
20    07/05/2011    0       0   0
21    08/05/2011    0       0   0
22    09/05/2011    0       0   0
23    10/05/2011    18000   0   0
24    11/05/2011    18000   0   0
25    12/05/2011    18000   0   0
26    13/05/2011    18000   0   0
27    14/05/2011    18000   0   0
28    15/05/2011    18000   0   0
29    16/05/2011    18000   0   0
30    17/05/2011    18000   0   0
31    18/05/2011    18000   0   0
32    19/05/2011    18000   0   0
33    20/05/2011    18000   0   0
34    21/05/2011    18000   0   0
35    22/05/2011    18000   0   0
```

[image: Notably, the chart isn't reading it entirely right, either.]

Comment: You cannot show a range containing more than one cell in a single cell. Your offset formula results in a range.

Comment: I am not getting any error at all using the GI formula with your example.

Comment: @Sun, so I've set the code to, for example, "=OFFSET(Graph!$C$8,4,0,0)". This would return the 4th row down from the point of origin, correct? It however is resulting in #REF!.

Comment: @ShaunGreatrix yes because the last two parameters of OFFSET are height and width of the area. If you set them to 0, no cell is referenced. You need to have `=OFFSET(Graph!$C$8,4,0,1,1)` to reference the fourth cell below the origin.

Comment: @Sun I see. So for my X axis, the date, I would need a range as that is what the Chart Horizontal Axis refers to - how best would I return that? Many thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't really understand what your critieria are for your range. If we take your Information-table above, what range exactly would you need to be referenced? B23:B35?

Comment: @Sun the idea is to draw incrementing lines across a chart, between dates X and Y as per the drop-down found at the top-left. The lines to be drawn are GI, IE and EE, which are plotted per-day on another sheet.

Comment: Addendum; I was under the impression to pull a user-selected range into a chart, you use a Name, which is designated as a cell range (i.e.; B23:B35).

Comment: Yes, you are right about the necessity for a named range. Just for clarification, the table itself in A:E does not change based on the dropdowns, right?

Comment: @Sun Changing the "FROM" date will change the dates found in A:A. B:B changes accordingly, whereas it will turn blank once it hits the "TO" date. GI/IE/EE then pull data via VLOOKUP and MATCH, by Job Query VS Date.

Comment: I would presume the syntax would be OFFSET([Point of Origin],[Location to start the range - Y],[Location to start the range - X],[Location to end the range - Y],[Location to end the range - X])

Comment: Just an FYI here you dont need ">"&0, you could have used ">0".  Also the way the formulas are currently set up it looks like you are trying to return the full range of your data.  As such, the -1 will prevent you from returning the date in the last row.  However based on comments this may be a none issue as you will be looking up based on a a supplied criteria.

Comment: the synteax for offset is, OFFSET(REFERENCE POINT, How many rows to move from reference point, How many columns to move from reference point, how many rows to return, how many columns to return)

Comment: OFFSET functions are volatile functions, meaning they recalculate any time something in the worksheet changes.  So if you wind up using a lot of volatile formulas you can eventually really wind up bogging down your sheet.  Now if you only have a few volatile functions it will not be an issue.

Comment: @ForwardEd could you define "Move" and "Return" ? I thought, for example;     OFFSET(A1,0,0,1,0) would return a value of A1:A2 ?

Comment: move as in 0 move 0 cells, 1 moves 1 cell right or down, -1 moves one cell up or left.  Returns meaning how many cells to include in the results. so a 1,0 return means bring back 1 row of cells and 0 columns of cells.  the 0 columns of cells is a bit of an issue.

Comment: I think I've found the issue. The errors are occuring because IE and EE have no values. I've set the CountIf to result in at least 1 (1+Countif([...])), which has stopped the errors. My chart is now showing a single blue line (GI) going up to 18000, but not the further 33000. By placing a 2 at the start of the GI range, it includes the further steps... which leads me to believe it's having issues with my CountIf looking for ">0". In short, is there an alternative to ">0" for search all blank cells, excluding formula?

Comment: @ShaunGreatrix  I thought the countif was there just for sample data.  Take a look a sun's answer and see how he has modified to look at all dates in before your end date.  I pulled a similar technique using Index (non volatile) instead offset (volatile). and modified it to pull only dates between your start and end range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should create the correct named Range for date:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$8,0,0,MATCH(Sheet1!$D$4,Sheet1!$B$8:$B$2927,0),1)
```

For GI:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$8,0,1,MATCH(Sheet1!$D$4,Sheet1!$B$8:$B$2927,0),1)
```

For IE:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$8,0,2,MATCH(Sheet1!$D$4,Sheet1!$B$8:$B$2927,0),1)
```

For EE:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$8,0,3,MATCH(Sheet1!$D$4,Sheet1!$B$8:$B$2927,0),1)
```

(D4 contains the end date dropdown.)

In the data selection for the graph, it is important to write the named Range including the sheet it's on, e.g.: `=Sheet1!nrDate` instead of just `=nrDate`.

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I tried adding sheet1!X_axis when I did mine, and it switched the sheet reference to the book1! reference on me.

Comment: Legend! Not sure what you did entirely, but it worked! Many thanks! http://imgur.com/SdnKggi

Comment: @ShaunGreatrix  All you need to do now is make an adjustment to your formula to account for the starting date as well.  hint you will need to substract it from your return size match too.

Comment: @ForwardEd this is when you set the validity of the named range to the whole workbook, instead of only the worksheet. Basically you can reference your range from the whole workbook, while mine is only addressable from Sheet1.

Comment: @ForwardEd I thought the starting date was already adjusted in the datatable itself, based on the comments in his question above. (--> it's always B8)

Comment: @sun reference starting range, if so, I missed that comment completely

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes, there is quite a lot of comments up there now :D anyways, it's this one: `@Sun Changing the "FROM" date will change the dates found in A:A. B:B changes accordingly, whereas it will turn blank once it hits the "TO" date. GI/IE/EE then pull data via VLOOKUP and MATCH, by Job Query VS Date. – Shaun Greatrix`

Answer (score 1):

So based on your data, an going a slightly different route than offset (offset route should work)  I used the index route.

for the x axis I used

```
=INDEX($B$9:$B$36,MATCH($C$5,$B$9:$B$36,0)):INDEX($B$9:$B$36,MATCH($D$5,$B$9:$B$36,0))
```

I used a defined name of X_axis

[image: X_axis]

for the y axis I used

```
=INDEX($C$9:$C$36,MATCH($C$5,$B$9:$B$36,0)):INDEX($C$9:$C$36,MATCH($D$5,$B$9:$B$36,0))
```

I used a define name of Y_axis.  For your second series on the Y axis, you would need to change the reference range from C9:C36, to the appropriate column that is lined up with your dates.

When defining the series, I had to use the workbook name in conjunction with the named range.  so series data looked like this:

[image]

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

Comment: I had never thought of using index/match in such a context, that was pretty educational :D

Comment: @Sun Originally I had it INDEX(INDEX(MATCH()):INDEX(MATCH()),0)  and I thought to myself, do I really need the first index in a named range.  Tested in and apparently I did not!  Its all based off something Jeeped told me and that is INDEX actually returns a cell address and not the content of the cell.  Excel will interpret the address and pull the cell values afterwards...or atleast it was something along those lines 8)